# Fragment getting Detached onPictureTake

Tags: android, android-fragments, camera

I have an activity and have a fragment in it, the fragment contains a CUSTOM CAMERA in it so all the coding for the camera is done in the fragment, but taking the Picture is called from the activity.

```
private void takePicture() {

    if (CameraFragment.mIsSafeToTakePhoto) {
        camFrag.setSafeToTakePhoto(false);

        //CameraFragment.mOrientationListener.rememberOrientation();

        // Shutter callback occurs after the image is captured. This can
        // be used to trigger a sound to let the user know that image is taken
        Camera.ShutterCallback shutterCallback = null;

        // Raw callback occurs when the raw image data is available
        Camera.PictureCallback raw = null;

        // postView callback occurs when a scaled, fully processed
        // postView image is available.
        Camera.PictureCallback postView = null;

        // jpeg callback occurs when the compressed image is available
        CameraFragment.mCamera.takePicture(shutterCallback, raw, postView, camFrag);
    }
}
```

take picture is the Library Method
Now,

The problem is, after taking the picture. OnPictureTake is called, and at this staged the Fragment is detached from the activity hence getActivity is returning null, alternate to that, if explicitly defining the activity, its giving an error, fragment is not attached to the activity.

Following is the code to take picture.

```
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
      rotation = getPhotoRotation();
    CameraModel cameraModel = new CameraModel();
    cameraModel.setCameraData(data, rotation, mImageParameters.createCopy());


    setSafeToTakePhoto(true);
}
```

The cameraModel here is the Getter and Setter for the DATA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem by implement Camer.PictureCallback in the Parent activity instead in the Fragment.